# MacOS 10.14.4 update failing to fully load and cycling through boot attempts but not loading requiring full recovery

Tags: macos, mojave, recovery

Noobie here.  I have tried to update my iMacPro Desktop to MacOS 10.14.4 and each time I do so it stalls part way through the update process and loops between Boot and Shut Down.  Each time this happens my only option is to fully recover the machine from a full backup in Time Machine.  All advice gratefully received.

Answer (score 3):

I got it to load properly by entering Disk Utility and running First Aid on the HD (instead of going to the full recovery mode as I had been doing)and then when I rebooted it booted into 10.14.4 all AOK!!